# Python how to use filecmp.cmp to do a non shallow comparison?

Tags: python, python-2.6

From http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.2/library/filecmp:

> filecmp.cmp(f1, f2[, shallow])
>
> Compare the files named f1 and f2, returning True if they seem equal, False otherwise.
>
> Unless shallow is given and is false, files with identical os.stat() signatures are taken to be equal.

I do not want to perform a shallow comparison, so what should I supply the shallow argument?

Answer (score 2):

False.  That's what it says.  Give it and make it false if you don't want a shallow comparison.

Comment: so I have to supply True for shallow when I dont want a shallow comparison!?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  See my edited answer.  You provide shallow=False when you don't want shallow.

Comment: @Fëanor No, you have to supply True for shallow when you DO want a shallow comparison.

Comment: @Yuushi: Technically you can just not supply shallow at all in that case, according to the doc.